# R MarkDown unable to generate HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

ON KNITTING a RMD it's throwing out an error in mac
as showed here.

> Error: 'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'
>   Execution halted

Note: I have recent version of knitr_1.17 and rmarkdown_1.9

Comment: Show us your yaml header or the code where the problem appears.

Comment: I think it is a bug and has been fixed.  Please check: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/pull/1271

Comment: Hi all, i have updated knitr to 1.18, and it's started woking as expected.thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating knitR package it started working as expected